# what is the best surface to run on?

Tags: running

running daily in the morning is my routine.i want to know the best surface for running which helps me to be fit.

Comment: Any surface that isn't dangerous. The actual deflection that you feel in a typical running shoe can't really be determined for any paved surface.

Comment: Best surface for health or performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of a generalized question, so this will be a generalized answer.

First of all, before getting in to things, the best answer is: the best surface for running is the one that's safest and most convenient. If you're only running a few KM, then the surface really doesn't matter that much, so safety and convenience take priority. Endurance runners (20+ km), may have to take in other things for consideration.

There are two aspects to think about when thinking of running surfaces: degree of incline and material.

**Degree of Incline**

Ideally you want to run on a surface where your hips are level. Meaning, when you're standing, your feet should be on an even plane. Prolonged running on an uneven surface can lead to imbalances and injuries. The higher degree of lateral incline, the worse it is.

The incline that you're running in to matters less with regards to health and safety.  Running in a positive incline will be harder. The steeper the incline the harder it will be. This can be beneficial.

Running on a decline **can** be harmful if you are not careful. On particularly steep inclines, people get scared of falling over so they lean back, but they're also going really fast, so the combination tends to cause a lot of hard heel strikes. So if you live in a very hilly area, it is to your benefit to learn how to *run* or at least *lightly jog* down the decline so that you're not breaking against gravity.

**Surface Material**

In this instance, you are looking for how hard the material is and how much traction it gives.

The best kind of overall surface is the are [Tartan tracks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartan_track) or whatever competing variety there is. This is the material you see on running tracks, and they are literally made for running. The surface is made of rubber so it is soft. It's also very porous so there is a lot of friction. You can even run in the rain if you wanted (it's nice. I recommend it if it's warm enough and no lightning).

Though tracks are hard to find, so the more common types of surfaces are asphalt and cement. Both provide a lot of traction. Though they have different levels of softness.

Asphalt is what they make roads out of. It's the softer of the two because it has to be able to support cars and trucks. Since they are roads, the surfaces also tend to be very flat and even. The downside is, of course, you have to worry about cars and trucks. The drivers of which will not be happy to see you running in the middle of the road. However, if you happen to find a long road that has very low traffic, it is a good choice. Some cities will also make long walking trails out of asphalt which would be a great place to run if you're lucky enough to be around one.

Cement is what they make sidewalks out of. It's super hard. The sidewalk itself may not be very good depending on how well they are kept. Though sometimes it is the only choice for safety reasons.

An alternate approach is trail running. Trails are made of dirt which is soft. The traction depends on how dry it is. Trails also have a wide variety of inclines which range from gentle slopes to extreme inclines. It is a good choice, but sometimes can be out of the way.